# Couchbase XDCR Activity

Tags: couchbase

I've got two Couchbase 2.0 servers in a cluster running on Server 2008 on AWS.  I have another two servers in a cluster in my own private data center (2008R2).  As an experiment, I set up XDCR between the AWS servers and the private datacenter.

I was replicating two buckets, one with about 5,000 items and the other with about 650k items.  Total size of the data was about 2.5 gb stored on disk or 6 gb stored in RAM (not sure why the large difference, but that's what the report shows - in previous versions of CB, the disk and ram sizes were roughly equivalent).

Anyway, the destination cluster (my data center) shows continuous activity (on the order of ~200 ops per second), even though it appears that all the items have been replicated over.  The source cluster has much lower activity (bursts of ~2k items per second every minute or so).  Is this normal behavior for CB, or is there a problem?

I ended up shutting the replication down because I'm concerned about incurring unnecessary data transfer costs.

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Can you report that here http://www.couchbase.com/issues/?

Comment: Yes, I'll do that when I get some time - thanks for your response.

Comment: I'm also getting these error messages, not sure if it's related since they are on the destination cluster, what are your thoughts?  http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/MB-6052?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:worklog-tabpanel

Comment: It wasn't your main question. but the reason the data only takes 2.5Gb on disk and 6Gb on RAM is that the data is compressed on the disk...

Comment: @RoeeGavirel - I don't think that's true. The processor overhead would be too great. I believe it can be done prior to giving your data to CB, but CB does not compress your data for you.

Comment: @rmayer06 - I've checked with the Couchbase guys and what they said is that binary data (anything but JSON) is not compressed but if you provide the data as JSON object it is compressed before being stored to disk.

Comment: @RoeeGavirel - thank you for following up on that. My data in this case is binary - it uses Protocol Buffers to serialize, so already highly compressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to post as a follow-up to this, that after installing the latest version of Couchbase, this issue went away on its own. It was clearly a 2.0 bug (one of many), so to those of you reading, always ensure you are working with the latest edition of Couchbase as the team really does make substantial improvements between releases.